# Ellipsis of "to" in successive infinitives

Tags: infinitives, ellipses

[Fowler's Dictionary of Modern English Usage](https://books.google.es/books?id=w1WuDwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA411&dq=(%20a%20)%20When%20a%20second%20infinitive%20is%20used%20after%20a%20to-infinitive%2C%20the%20second%20(and%20third%2C%20etc.)%20example%20is%20not%20necessarily%20preceded%20by%20to.%20Contrast%20%E2%80%98can%20be%20induced%20to%20move%20or%20to%20change%20its%20orientation%E2%80%99%20with%20%E2%80%98I%20prefer%20not%20to%20live%20and%20work%20in%20the%20same%20room&hl=es&pg=PA411#v=onepage&q=(%20a%20)%20When%20a%20second%20infinitive%20is%20used%20after%20a%20to-infinitive,%20the%20second%20(and%20third,%20etc.)%20example%20is%20not%20necessarily%20preceded%20by%20to.%20Contrast%20%E2%80%98can%20be%20induced%20to%20move%20or%20to%20change%20its%20orientation%E2%80%99%20with%20%E2%80%98I%20prefer%20not%20to%20live%20and%20work%20in%20the%20same%20room&f=false) reads

> When a second infinitive is used after a *to*-infinitive, the second
> (and third, etc.) example is not necessarily preceded by *to*.
> Contrast ‘*can be induced **to** move or **to** change its orientation*’ with
> *‘I
> prefer not **to** live and work in the same room*’

Aren't *to move* and *to change* infinives in the first sentence too?

Comment: Fowler gives examples of non-ellipsis and ellipsis (hence 'Contrast'). All four possibilities here are grammatical, but I prefer these style choices. // I’m voting to close this as essentially a non-question.

Comment: Yes, they are infinitives, too. Fowler says a repeated infinitive "is not necessarily preceded by _to_". That means the _to_ might appear, as it does in the first pair, or not, as in the second.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth why are the preferred wordings different? All I can see is that the first sentence has a past participle wheras the second a verb (_prefer_).

Comment: No, that's not a factor. There's more of a contrast in the first sentence (move / change orientation). It's not just the disjunction; 'Students are forbidden to eat or drink in the library' but 'The squid were unable to change colour or to jet to safety after being fed vindaloo extract'. // 'Live and work ...' is pretty coherent.

Comment: Yes, they are plain forms (your infinitives). Why would you doubt that? The subordinator "to" is not part of the verb, but a special marker for the VPs of infinitival clauses. In your first example, "... [to move] or [to change]" form a coordination of two infinitival clauses linked by "or". In your second example "to [live and work]" "live" and "work" form a coordination, not of two clauses, but of two verb phrases.

Comment: @BillJ yes, but what are the guidelines for choosing one or the other?

Comment: There is a lot of information about this on the 'Net. Have you looked? Incidentally, it's not a matter of ellipsis. "To" is not part of the verb, but a marker of infinitival VPs.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest terms, the second “**to**” adds emphasis and, often, separation. That emphasis is used to enhance the context.

I want you **to verb1 and to verb2** indicates two distinct actions. *I want you to wash the car and to dig the garden.* The context should indicate why the two actions are, or need to be, distinct.

I want you **to verb1 and verb2** indicates simultaneous actions. *I want you to wait and see what happens.*

In *I want you to verb1 and verb2*, **verb1 and verb2** could be considered as one action/verb or that they are on a continuum.

*‘(It) can be induced to move or to change its orientation’* = *‘(It) can be induced [**either**] to move [in a straight line] **or** to change its orientation [but not both or both at the same time].’*

*‘(It) can be induced [**both**] to move and change its orientation’* The action of the infinitives take place at the same time: there is movement and change.

*‘I prefer not to live and work in the same room’* Both verbs share the same modifier. The action of the infinitives takes place at the same time.

*‘I prefer not to live here or to work with you’* Neither verb shares the same modifier. The time of the action of the infinitives is unconnected/separate.

*I want you to eat and enjoy the meal*. Both infinitives share the same object and their action takes place at the same time.

*I want you to stand up and to watch the horizon.* The actions of the infinitives are separate – first you stand still, then you watch the horizon.

*I want you to stand up and watch the horizon.* The action of the infinitives takes place at the same time as part of a continuum – you will be standing up and watching the horizon - there is no separation in the actions.

*I want you to stand up or to watch the horizon.* The actions of the infinitives are separate – You can do one or the other, but not both.

*I want you to stand up or watch the horizon.* This is the same as above.

Comment: _Do you want **to live and die** in the wilderness?_  https://books.google.es/books?id=oX2DmE78bnYC&lpg=PA37&dq=%22want%20to%20live%20and%20die%22&hl=es&pg=PA37#v=onepage&q=%22want%20to%20live%20and%20die%22&f=false

Comment: @GJC Yes, exactly - (i) the verbs share the same modifier, (ii) the verbs describe a continuum - the second "to" is not required

Comment: Does "and" vs. "or" in the OP examples have anythig to do with the addition of "to"?